# WPF Tile Control like Windows 8 Start Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, user-interface, windows-8

So, does anyone knows a panel or a control which emulate Windows 8 Stat Menu Tile Panel?

with all of those features like SQUAD tiles or bigger ones?

Also i have seen this link on Stack overflow, but because of low reputation points, i could comment there that "IT DOESN'T WORK"

[Emulates Windows 8 Start Menu Tile Layout Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407177/any-wpf-panel-layout-code-that-emulates-the-windows-8-start-menu-tile-layout-eng)

Comment: -1 Wow! You have a link to an answer that has done 95% of the work for you and that's *still* not enough??? Are you a developer, or just a collector of other people's work?

Comment: thank you for politeness, but in my idea it's not even 1% of work!!
not only doesn't work, it's basically a wrong algorithm, the only OK in that code is overriding `ArrangeOverride`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is: no, there is no native control which emulate a tile.

Thus, basically, you could do it yourslef as explained in the link you provide: [Emulates Windows 8 Start Menu Tile Layout Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407177/any-wpf-panel-layout-code-that-emulates-the-windows-8-start-menu-tile-layout-eng)

If it does not work, you probably have something wrong because it is some classic XAML.

Another alternative could be to use a tiers-Library. There are some paying like [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/), [Actipro](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/devcraft?gclid=CjwKEAjwre6dBRC94d-Gma7g3wcSJACNatZeGjTn77vQNUDodBx9xb9RMYocYyQLrvREDTrU6gqklBoC4E_w_wcB).

But my recommandation would be: do not buy anything, but do not reinvent the Wheel either. You have some free nice Library available with Nugets like [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) or [ModernUI for WPF](https://mui.codeplex.com/) that could greatly help you to create your own custom tile.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik RAD Tile control can do it for you !