# Is it possible to create a Windows 10 tile control inside my application?

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, live-tile

I have a requirement wherein I have to create a list of item which are similar to Windows tile which we see in the Start Menu. Since the Start Menu tiles comes with default feature like like a pin and an ellipse button is shown on long press, is it possible to create such tiles inside my application so that those features comes by default. Any sample code or links to samples online will be helpful. [image: Attached screenshot of the behaviour on long press]

Comment: Take a look at this SO [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630251/wpf-tile-control-like-windows-8-start-menu).

Comment: Thanks Ruben, the article talks about the drag and drop feature but I am more concerned about the ellipse button and the pin feature which gets enabled on long press of tile on a touch device.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default control for your requirements. You need to create custom `UserControl` or new templace for the default ones.